# How to view the environment properties inside the EC2 in an Elastic Beanstalk environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've added an environment property to an Elastic Beanstalk environment.

[image]

I'd like to know how to view the value of `FOO` after I `ssh` into the EC2 instance that belongs to the Elastic Beanstalk environment.

I've tried `env | grep FOO`. But fails to find `FOO` variable in my environment.

The platform of the elastic beanstalk environment is `tomcat`. So I've also tried `sudo -Hiu tomcat env` command to see if the user `tomcat` has `FOO` variable. But `sudo -Hiu tomcat env` returns `This account is currently not available.` error.

Anyone knows how to read `FOO` variable inside the EC2 instance?

Comment: Try with `printenv`

Comment: Try with this command:  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment

Comment: `sudo /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment | grep FOO` works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to `Aress Support`'s comment. I use `sudo /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment | grep FOO` to get the value of `FOO`.